# How can Eclipse binaries search be configured to recognize .srec format?

Tags: eclipse, embedded, eclipse-cdt, srecord

I see that Eclipse CDT/Embedded has a capability to find binaries such as `.elf`, `.bin`, `.exe`... I was wondering whether this is configurable setting or not, since I would like it to add too the Motorola binary formatting called `.srec`.

Any hint on how or where I can add this onto Eclipse CDT?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: As the other binary formats include meta information, what do you want to see? The srec format encodes just binary data and its address without any more context. And it is an ASCII based format, you can use the default text editor to view it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @thebusybee I would like it to be listed as the rest of the binaries are under the binary list on the Project Explored

Answer (score 0):

SREC is an ASCII object file format so to use a binary search makes little sense.   You could use a text search, but to search for particular binary sequences that span more than one record would be complicated.

What you could do is convert the SREC file to a raw binary file, then use the binary search on that.  Conversion to raw binary can for example be done using  the [SRecord](http://srecord.sourceforge.net/) utility, e.g.:

```
    srec_cat myobject.srec −o myobject.bin −binary
```

If you add that as a post-build step, the binary version of your SREC file will always be available for searching.